# Could not find com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-multidex, android-viewpager2

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I'm getting this error after I added multidex in my project

Comment: Have you added _com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1_ in _build.gradle_ file?

Comment: yes    implementation 'com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

Comment: implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlinstdlib:$kotlin_version"implementation'androidx.core:corektx:1.6.0'implementation'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'implementation'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'implementation'androidx.constraintlayot:constraintlayout:2.1.0'implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-supportv4:1.0.0'testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'androidTestImplementation'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'androidTestImplementation'androidx.test.espresso:espressocore:3.4.0'implementation'com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

Comment: Must be sure _multiDexEnabled true_ is enabled. For more check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.mapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }      yes I added already but still it is error

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

**implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'**
not **implementation 'com.androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'**